# Unable to see vertical scroll bar in datagrid when placed inside grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

From last 2 day I am stuck in a small problem which I don't know why I was not able to solve it. I had did lots off goggling and implemented various suggestion provided by stack overflow to solve out the problem but finally I am getting tired off by unsuccessful implementation.

My problem is that I want a scroll able data grid which could be placed inside a Grid control or DockPanel(As I had tried with both). Below is code which I am using.

```
<Grid IsEnabled="{Binding IsCalcVarGridPartEnable}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisiblityConverter" />
        <sys.converters:BoolToVisibleHiddenConvertor x:Key="boolToVisibleHiddenConvertor"/>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement"
                     DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource SeperatorStyle}" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BannerTextStyle}" Text="Calculation Variable" />
    </Border>

    <Border Style="{StaticResource SeperatorStyle}" Grid.Row="2">
        <Button Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,5" Command="{Binding EditCalcVarCmd}" />
    </Border>

    <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed"
            Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              Name="dataGridCalcVar" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              IsReadOnly="True"                       
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"                  
              ItemsSource="{Binding CalcVarCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCalcVar}"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                    
                  >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" >
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalcVarDoubleClickedCmd}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" />
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="DataGridCellStyle" />
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type Description" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200" Binding="{Binding CalcTypName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Variable Description" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200" Binding="{Binding CalcVarName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Major Description" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200" Binding="{Binding MjAcctTypDesc}" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsMjMiAcctTypVisible, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},
                                Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibleHiddenConvertor}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Minor Description" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200" Binding="{Binding MiAcctTypDesc}" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsMjMiAcctTypVisible, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},
                                Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibleHiddenConvertor}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DNA Value" MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="200" Binding="{Binding CalcVarValueName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Critical Value" MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="200" Binding="{Binding CriticalValueName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Note" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200" Binding="{Binding Note}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <sysclient:PartStatusView Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
        Style="{DynamicResource PartStatusViewDefaultStyle}" IsTabStop="False"/>
</Grid>
```

Important: I am able to get scroll bar only when I set max height of Datagrid control but I don't want to set max-height property of either row or datagrid control. I want that when I resize window or whatever space is available datagrid is set into that space and when we query the data then if data data is greater than available space then data grid brings vertical scroll bar.

Please help me!!!!!

I hope I am able to explain my problem. :-) :-)

Thanks,

Comment: Where is this `Grid` placed/used? Is one of parents of that `Grid` a `StackPanel` by any chance?

Comment: Parent of grid is user control.

Comment: And what is the parent of that `UserControl`? Go up the visual tree and see if you have somewhere along the way control like `StackPanel` or `Canvas`

Comment: Actually I am using a framework control provided by core developers . So there should be panel or content control.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there are two attributes which can help you here

add `Grid.Row="1"` to your data grid

remove `VerticalAlignment="Top"` from the same which actually prevent it to take height from the container

eg

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Name="dataGridCalcVar" 
          Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          IsReadOnly="True"                       
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"                  
          ItemsSource="{Binding CalcVarCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCalcVar}"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

I am assuming that you want to place grid in the middle row which takes up the remaining space.

Comment: This solution did not work. Datagrid height increases to show all data but scrollbar is not showing.

Comment: i tested it is working as expected, all what i could not test is any styles and templates you have. is it possible for you to post a working sample of your code which shows this issue?